# How do I hide or unhide a form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I thought this would have been a legal statement but obviously not How do I hide or unhide a form based on this?

```
TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm searchform = new TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm(context);
if (searchform == null)
    searchform.ShowDialog();
else
    searchform.Visible = true;
```

Comment: searchform will never be null if you instantiate it right above your if statement.

Comment: And even if it was, you'd get a NullPointerException, trying to show it when it's null.

Comment: Whats the error or not working? And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: you can call formName.Hide() to hide a form.

Comment: I Think you can simply use .Hide() and .Show() method, and nothing more.

Comment: Sorry Should have explained I am trying to hide this form from search button on the search form ? then make it visible from the calling form again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, my code for Form1 which has a button that shows Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 f2 = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (f2 == null) { f2 = new Form2(); }
            f2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

and on Form2, I put a textbox with no events (but its text is remembered between hiding and showing Form2), and it has a button that hides its form. here's the code for Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnHideMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Edaward but as you see here im passing my entity context thru to 


                TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm searchform = new TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm(context);

Comment: i need to be able to pass that context object which is declaire in the form load handler

Comment: okay, I modified my code to create the form in the button event. but notice that I must still declare my `f2` variable outside the button method so it will not be forgotten. so you were close in your original, in testing it for null. :) but you need to declare the variable in form scope, not inside the method. my code shows you full source code on how this is done. :) Happy coding, @DavidB!

Comment: here is my full code in a paste bin to show you what i meen 

http://pastebin.com/E9LRRgcn

Comment: sorry, I am behind a firewall and cannot access that at this time. and my break time is over. I will try to look at it this evening at home and see if you got it resolved and if not, then i'll try to see from your code what you need. :)

Comment: Well, David, in line 37 of your posted code, the 'context' variable is declared with form-scope so the 'context' variable can be 'seen' or used in any method of the form. that's very good news for you. in line 63, that variable is set, so it is given a value then, when the form is created. so it's available in the whole form, in any method. so you will want to do just what my answer code has, but with your own variables. and where I have `f2 = new Form2();`, yours would be `searchform = new TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm(context);`. the 'context' variable gives you no problems.

Comment: so all you need in your solution is to change line 825 from `TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm searchform = new TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm(context);` to `if (searchform == null) { searchform = new TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm(context); }`. and you need to declare the searchform variable in form-scope so it is remembered between each time your button is pressed, like I did in my code above. it seems to me, inside your 'Private properties' region is a good place between lines 33 and 55. you'll want that declaration to be: `TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm searchform = null;`.

Comment: thanks how to I show the form though if its already been created

Comment: at last someone who makes the effort on stack overflow kudos to @Edward ;-)

Comment: you show the form with the Show() method of the form variable: `searchform.Show();`. In my code above, it is this: `f2.Show();
`.

Answer (score 7):

to show or hide a Windows Form, you use the Show() or Hide() methods, like this: `searchform.Show();` or `searchform.Hide();`

You might want to consider this code:

```
TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm searchform = new TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm(context);
if (searchform.Visible == false)
{    searchform.Show();   }
else
{    searchform.Hide();   }
```

Comment: I am calling the form then on the close button of second form calling hide() i would have persumed calling it this way the form would remember the values of the controls

Comment: if you want a 2nd form to hide itself, you might want to catch the Closing() event rather than the Close() event. Then on the Closing() event, just hide the form *and* cancel the closing event (with `e.Cancel = true` where 'e' is the `FormClosingEventArgs` variable. This prevents it from really closing, but just hides it. Then when you reshow it, it should remember everything. That's the first thing i'd try. :)

Comment: oh, the previous comment was assuming you were trying to hide it from the Close event. nevermind. if you just hide it from a button click, then I would assume it would remember control values too, like the text inside text boxes on the hidden form.

Comment: its not im afriad ;-( i click close on search on the child form it hides the child form but then I want to reload same form that been hidden on a button click ?

Comment: ah, but when you declare your `TrainingEventAddTraineesSearchForm searchform` you are creating that searchform variable inside your button event method, I assume? that would cause the problem of it not remembering it. it needs to be in the main form, but outside your button event method.

Comment: im reference another object which is calle in on activate method which means need to be their you c the context bit?

Comment: please see my other answer with full source code, for a simple 2 form project (Form1 and Form2) which remembers the data in Form2 when it is hidden and reshown.